# How to make child fixed DIV relative to parent fixed div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Their CSS are as follows:

```
.parent {
  position: fixed;
}
.child {
  position: fixed;
  left: calc(100% - 10%);
}
```

Since both the parent and child are having fixed positions, is there a way that I can make child relative to the parent?

Originally, I wanted to have this:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - 10%);
}
```

But, the parent here is a header that remains fixed at the top of every page. Therefore, I can't change it to relative. However, I can do change the child from fixed to absolute if I want to but that is not a concern here. I want the child to be relative to the parent so that the styling has more accuracy for all screen sizes by default. Any workaround for this?

Comment: parent fixed and child absolute?

Comment: @TemaniAfif are you asking me or suggesting me?

Comment: both ..............

Comment: Also just a note, why do a `calc()` on those percentages? Why not simply put it at `90%` to remove the overhead from having to do a `calc()`?

Comment: @Martin actually while writing it here it was a mistake.. It should be `100% - 10px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question - but here's a snippet to demonstrate that if you position child in relation to its fixed positioned parent it works.

```css
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  top: 10vh; /* just to prove child is positioned relative to parent not to body */
  background-color: lime;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% - 10%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```